# creating img src using JavaScript returns broken img

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I iterate some JSON in order to obtain URLs of images in order to display them in a table.

The JavaScript code I'm using to do so is ( I generate a table and then populate cells in each row where the first cell in the row is an image and all the rest are strings):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
    var newRow = document.createElement('tr')
    newRow.classList.add('table-row')
    for (var j = 0; j < data.result[i].length; j++) {
        if (j == 0){
            var newCell = document.createElement('img');
            newCell.src = data.result[i][j];
            console.log(data.result[i][j])
            newCell.style.width = 50;
            newCell.style.height = 50;
        } else {
            var newCell = document.createElement('td');
            newCell.classList.add('col')
            newCell.innerHTML = data.result[i][j];
        }
        newRow.appendChild(newCell);
    }
    table[0].appendChild(newRow)
}
```

Where `data.result[i][j]` contains the URL.

For example, In one of the cases I get:

```
newCell.src = 'https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Mithril bar#/media/File:Mithril bar_detail.png'
```

Now, when I click on that URL it indeed displays me an image. However, when I use the code above Im getting a broken image:

[image]

Any reason that I won't show the image?

I thought maybe it is due to that preview on the website but not sure how to deal with it.

Thank you

Comment: You need to encode the url.

Comment: I tried to use .replace(" ", "%20") but it still gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL is not really pointing to an image.

If you go to the link and right click on the image and "open image in new tab" you get this link:

https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/images/thumb/b/b5/Mithril_bar_detail.png/1280px-Mithril_bar_detail.png?c7a7b

Comment: I also thought so but is there any way I can use the image in the link I posted? (It is the only method I can think of generating automatic URLs)

Comment: If you have a backend for your app, you can make a GET request to the link and search for the HTML element with the class "png" with something like document.getElementsByClassName("png"). Out of this element you can extract the real url

Answer (score 0):

The image URL you provided is not rendered in the DOM. Try this one instead:

```
https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/images/b/b5/Mithril_bar_detail.png?c7a7b
```

Comment: You might explain where you got that URL. It's not at all clear from your answer.